# routes of lazy loaded modules completely re-loads the app

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

i have my routes setup like this.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
path: '',
redirectTo: '/',
pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
path: 'bank-manager',
loadChildren: () => import('./bank-manager/bank-manager.module').then(m => m.BankManagerModule),
canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
 {
path: 'account-holder',
loadChildren: () => import('./account-holder/account-holder.module').then(m => 
 m.AccountHolderModule),
canActivate: [AuthGuard]
   },
    {
   path: '**',
   redirectTo: ''
 }
 ];
```

i have a login button that is attached to an ngrx store and store is working fine. when i login a required values are set in the store. and i want that user should not be able to go to a child route if they are not logged in. so i have an authGuard set up like this

```
    @Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, private router: Router) {}

canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.pipe(
    select(isLoggedInSelector),
    tap((loggedIn) => {
        if (!loggedIn) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        }
    })
    );
}
}
```

so i go to localhost:4200 and then i click login this changes the store as required. but when i manually goto
*localhost:4200/account-holder* it reloads the entire app and store values are lost.

what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Apart from your problem, you should be using a `canLoad ` route guard when it comes to lazily loaded modules. if `canActivate` returns false, the module would be loaded anyway, which is something that might not be desired. `canLoad` ensures that if the guard fails, the module **won't be loaded at all**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to return true / false in all cases.

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        protected readonly router: Router,
        protected readonly store: Store,
    ) {}

    public canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.store.pipe(
            select(isLoggedInSelector),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            switchMap(flag => {
                if (flag) {
                    return of(flag);
                }
                return from(this.router.navigate(['/'])).pipe(mapTo(false));
            }),
        );
    }
}
```

if you mean manually - you put the url in your browser and open a fresh copy of your angular app - it won't work. The store keeps data in memory and you need a side solution to make it persistent, for example you can use [ngrx-store-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-store-localstorage), then every time you open the app it will restore store from local storage.

Comment: thank-you i implemented local-storage and it makes sense now.